# Bitcoin: parsing Blockchain API JSON in PyQT

Tags: python, json, api, pyqt, bitcoin

The following link provides data in JSON regarding a BTC adress -> https://blockchain.info/address/1GA9RVZHuEE8zm4ooMTiqLicfnvymhzRVm?format=json.

The bitcoin adress can be viewed here --> https://blockchain.info/address/1GA9RVZHuEE8zm4ooMTiqLicfnvymhzRVm

As you can see in the first transaction on **2014-10-20 19:14:22**, the TX had 10 inputs from 10 adresses. I want to retreive these adresses using the API, but been struggling to get this to work. The following code only retrieves the first adress instead of all 10, see code. I know it has to do with the JSON structure, but I cant figure it out.

```
import json
import urllib2
import sys


#Random BTC adress (user input)
btc_adress = ("1GA9RVZHuEE8zm4ooMTiqLicfnvymhzRVm")

#API call to blockchain
url = "https://blockchain.info/address/"+(btc_adress)+"?format=json"
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(json_obj)

#Put tx's into a list
txs_list = []
for txs in data["txs"]:
    txs_list.append(txs)

#Cut the list down to 5 recent transactions
listcutter = len(txs_list)
if listcutter >= 5:
    del txs_list[5:listcutter]

# Get number of inputs for tx
recent_tx_1 = txs_list[1]
total_inputs_tx_1 = len(recent_tx_1["inputs"])
```

**The block below needs to put all 10 input adresses in the list 'Output_adress'. It only does so for the first one;**

```
output_adress = []
output_adress.append(recent_tx_1["inputs"][0]["prev_out"]["addr"])

print output_adress
```

Your help is always appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you only add one address to it. Change it to this:

```
output_adress = []
for i in xrange(len(recent_tx_1["inputs"])):
    output_adress.append(recent_tx_1["inputs"][i]["prev_out"]["addr"])
print output_adress
```